# Dynamically create nodes in JTree from a SQL query

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

I have a hierarchical structure like this:

```
Lot
 |_Stages
    |_Samples
```

Example:

```
Lot1
 |_Stage1
     |_Sample11 
     |_Sample12 
 |_Stage2
     |_Sample21 
     |_Sample22
```

The idea is that the user will provide a LotID and based on this my SQL query retrieves all the Stages and also all samples within each stage.

I save each record in the result set as a custom Object and add it to an Array List.

Example of Result Set output:

> LotID  ||    LotCondition  ||    StageID  ||    StageCondition  ||    SampleID  ||    SampleCondition
>
> --------||  --------------  ||  ------------  || --------------------  || ------------|| ----------------
>
> 5001   ||  Dispositioned ||  4001   ||  Complete  ||  3001 || Approved
>
> 5001   ||  Dispositioned ||  4001   ||  Complete  ||  3002 || Approved
>
> 5001   ||  Dispositioned ||  4002   ||  Complete  ||  3003 || Approved
>
> 5001   ||  Dispositioned ||  4002   ||  Complete  ||  3004 || Approved
>
> 5002   ||  ReadyToRelease||  4003   ||  Complete  ||  3005 || Approved
>
> 5003   ||  Dispositioned ||  4004   ||  Complete  ||  3006 || Approved
>
> 5004   ||  Dispositioned ||  4004   ||  Complete  ||  3007 || Approved

From this array list I use a DefaultMutableTreeNode to add the objects to the Tree (i.e. new DefaultMutableTreeNode(custom_object.getLotID)..etc).

Now there are 2 issues:

1. There is only one unique LotID = 5001, but it displays 4 times (from example above) because there are 4 samples and hence 4 records.
2. My objective is to first retrieve the SampleIDs and add it to their respective StageIDs and finally add all the StageIDs to the LotID (root node).  I do not know how to display in a hierarchial manner.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction or some ideas?

Comment: Use some kind of factory, that given the row data, can generate the required nodes.  You'll probably want to pass a reference to the tree model are using.  I'd recommend using a `MutableTreeModel` and `MutableTreeNode`.  Take a look at [How to use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for more ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..I found a way to do this and thought I might share it. I did not use the MutableTreeModel.

I decided to create loops i.e. when the result set is retrived. For example: I fetch the result set for Stages and within in I try to fetch for all the Samples with in each Stage.

Now I had 2 options, one was to store these result sets into a DefaultMutableTreeNode or to store them in an ArrayList and HaspMap (for example: I could have created a HashMap for Stage IDs as my keys and its Samples in an ArrayList as its values. Then because we can pass in any type of object other than a DefaultMutableTreeNode object to a TreeModel, we can pass in this HashMap object and use a custom TreeModel to handle it. This would also require my objects saved in the Arraylists override the HashCode and Equals method.

But I think, for my application, it is simple to go with option 1.